# Elasticsearch 6 RestHighLevelClient: How to know when the result of an IndexRequest is ready to be read?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-6

I'm writing a unit test where I need to write to an Elasticsearch 6 index using a RestHighLevelClient in the Java Elasticsearch 6 library, then read from the index. How can I know when the results of an IndexRequest are ready to be read from the index via RestHighLevelClient.search? For example:

```
RestHighLevelClient client;
//client initialization
BulkRequest request = new BulkRequest();
request.add(new IndexRequest(...));
BulkResponse response = client.bulk(request);
//process response

SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest(...);
SearchResponse scrollResponse = client.search(request);
//scrollResponse is empty!
```

Basically, if I put a Thread.sleep between the write and the read, the response has the content I wrote, so I think the requests are being made properly. Is there a way I can be sure to wait until the `client.bulk(request)` part has completely finished writing before I do the read operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will force a refresh as part of this request.

```
request.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.IMMEDIATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. If anyone in the future happens to have this very specific problem, you need to include:

```
client.refreshIndex(indexName)
```

In between the write and the read. Elasticsearch refreshes by default every 1 second, but you can do this explicitly as well if you need to read <1 second after writing.